# Javascript ajax: Не получается взять инфо с сайта

Tags: ajax, javascript, html

Всем привет.

Проблема в том, что с одного сайта не получается взять инфо. Например, берем ссылку "http://www.owww.obnovi.com/main/8345-skachat-film-kak-ukrast-neboskreb-2011-besplatno.html". Делаю ajax запрос и вывожу в alert, получаю вот что:

[image: снимок]

С любым другим сайтом все нормально.. Либо сайт неправильно построен?
Может это быть из за того, что не указан какой документ? типо: "`!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN`"

Answer (score 1):

Перекодируйте в utf8, затем только используйте ajax. И будете жить долго и счастливо))

Comment: Почитайте мой комментарий на прошлый ответ.
Документ у меня кстати в utf8

Comment: @maza51 AJAX работает только с utf8. Грузить полностью сайт в див - бред, если хотите увидеть текст - создайте textarea и в него грузите.

Comment: @maza51 используй utf8 говорю тебе. какой бы ни была кодировка где-то там, перекодируйте в utf8 и только потом наслаждайся прелестями асинхронности. Иначе хоть петлю на шею - ничего у тебя выйдет.

Comment: Вконтакте тоже кстати на 1251 кодировке. И все нормально..

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы с кодировкой, попробуй сменить у себя кодировку в скрипте, что бы совпадало с кодировкой этой страницы

Comment: Я думаю, что не в кодировке дело. Потому что я создаю новый DIV и пихают туда все это, DIV тупо пустой и остается:

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = tmp_ajax;
    alert(div.innerHTML);

Алерт вообще не показывается.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте кодировку такую же, как и на сайте. А на сайте windows-1251.

Comment: Нет ризницы. Ты вот дал совет, а ты можешь обосновать его? Причем тут кодировка? 
Если тупо содержимое страницы не могу скопировать в див!

Comment: Конечно могу. Если отображаются "крякозябрики", то значит не правильная кодировка, неужели не понятно. А то что не вставляется в див, а алертом выводятся - то значит не правильно обращаешься или не правильно выводишь. Обосновать..... Кореектно вопрос научись задавать, потом наезжать будешь и обосновывать просить ....

Comment: Как обьясните то, что этим же способом я вывожу div в алерт совершенно любой другой сайт?

Answer (score 0):

Покажите как вы получаете значение tmp_ajax? Вас не смущает, что Вы пытаетесь в div вставить `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`?.. Или я не правильно понял?

Comment: У меня не помещается сюда код примера. В div я помещаю весь код страницы.